# Table Row Toggle in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have been stuck with this problem for a while now. I know that for table rows to animate smoothly you need `div`s. And I came over this solution where I can hide the `tablerow` I want, but I cannot make it appear again.

I need some if solution or maybe some toggle solution.

HTML:

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class="clickme">
                Sample text
            </td>
            <td class="clickme">$10</td>
            <td class="clickme">$100</td>
            <td class="clickme">$0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hideme">
            <td colspan="4">
                <div>
                    Sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="clickme">
                Sample text
            </td>
            <td class="clickme">$10</td>
            <td class="clickme">$100</td>
            <td class="clickme">$0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hideme">
            <td colspan="4">
                <div>
                    Sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="clickme">
                Sample text
            </td>
            <td class="clickme">$10</td>
            <td class="clickme">$100</td>
            <td class="clickme">$0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hideme">
            <td colspan="4">
                <div>
                    Sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="clickme">
                Sample text
            </td>
            <td class="clickme">$10</td>
            <td class="clickme">$100</td>
            <td class="clickme">$0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="hideme">
            <td colspan="4">
                <div>
                    Sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Jquery:

```
$('.hideme').find('div').hide();
$('.clickme').click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next('.hideme').find('div').slideToggle(500);
    return false;        
});
```

---

The right markup and Jquery is updated. Final JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NVx4S/21/

Comment: i think you have to make a better html structure.

Comment: Hmm, why? It's a simple table, with a tbody, two tr and som td in them?

Comment: simply because you are doing an huge use of js just to wrap the text with a div, while you can put that div already in the page without using js. then you can just use slideToggle()

Comment: something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/NVx4S/9/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td id="content-1" class="clickme">
                Sample text
                <!-- <a href="#content-1" class="clickme">Sample text</a> -->
            </td>
            <td>$10</td>
            <td>$100</td>
            <td>$0</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
           <td colspan="4">
               <div id="slide-content-1">
                  Sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text, sample text
               </div>
           </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>​
```

---

```
    $('.clickme').click(function() {
        //$(this.hash).slideToggle(500);
        $('#slide-'+this.id).slideToggle(500);
        return false;        
    });
```

Comment: Well, this works. But what I want to achive is to click the table row. And not a text in the row.

Comment: @Hardan: dear, honestly i can't see any substantial difference between click an anchor (that IMHO is the best way) and click a table row;  now, if you don't have control over the content, i can stand with you on using that huge piece of js code; otherwise there is no reason to do like so. see the updates.

Comment: @Hardan: i'm happy that it helped, btw, you have to accept (check) an answer or at least click a +1; tnx.

Answer (score 0):

I edited your JSFiddle a little bit. Does it help you?

http://jsfiddle.net/NVx4S/7/

Comment: First of all thank you for trying, but what I want to achive is the slide up and slide down effect. And that's only working if you contain the td's with divs.